# Определение значения checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

Как определить, поставил пользователь галочку на checkbox или же убрал ее? (Если ставит должно устанавливаться значение `aacept = true;` , а если убирает `aacept = false;`)

```
accept.addEventListener('change', () => {
                aacept = null;
                aacept = true;
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
accept.addEventListener('change', function() {
  aacept = this.checked;
});
```